# How can helium be liquid at absolute zero, given the Third Law of Thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter, temperature, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

I learned recently that Helium is a liquid even at 0K. Doesn't that mean that it still have some entropy? If so, does it not violate the postulate of thermodynamics that states that entropy must go to 0 as temperature goes to 0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is entropy of all systems zero at absolute zero?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109941/)

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin The two questions are related for sure, but this one is not completely answered by the one you cite.

Comment: I really haven't heard of liquid helium at 0 K. The last i heard that it was possible to reach a few microkelvins above 0K. We can never actually reach 0k.

Comment: This question was asked several times before...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Interesting question. The "third law" of thermodynamics actually states that

> The entropy of a **perfect crystal** at absolute zero is exactly zero.

Since many systems in nature crystallize at some point when their temperature is lowered, this statement is often misinterpreted as:

> The entropy of a **physical system** at absolute zero is exactly zero. (***wrong!***)

Entropy is defined as

$$S=k_B \log(\Omega)$$

where $\Omega$ is the number of microstates of the system. Since there is only one microstate corresponding to a perfect crystalline configuration, in the case of a crystal we have $\Omega=1$, and therefore $S=0$. But there are systems with a degenerate ground state, i.e. many different states of lowest energy, and also systems (like glasses) that get "stuck" and cannot reach their real ground state. Those system won't satisfy $\Omega=1$ at $T=0$, and therefore their entropy will be different from $0$.

You can find more about the correct interpretation of the "third law" [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/261002/115736) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/109944/115736).

Liquid helium is a unique case: it is the only element which remains liquid at atmospheric temperature down to $T=0$ and does not crystallize. Its phase diagram is shown in the picture below:

[image]

Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_helium-4):

> Below the $\lambda$-line the liquid can be described by the so-called
>   two-fluid model. It behaves as if it consists of two components: a
>   normal component, which behaves like a normal fluid, and **a superfluid
>   component with zero viscosity and zero entropy**. [...] By lowering the temperature, the fraction of the superfluid density increases from zero at $T_\lambda$ to one at zero kelvin. Below 1 K the helium is almost completely superfluid.

So, at $T=0$ $^4$He is completely superfluid and it has zero entropy. Why is this? Why is the entropy of a liquid $0$? Well, it's because liquid helium is no ordinary liquid.

In the superfluid state, all the atoms are in the [same quantum state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate). Moreover, they are identical. This means that there is in fact *only one ground state*, because if we exchange two atoms nothing changes. Therefore, the number of microstates is $\Omega=1$ and

$$S=0$$

Comment: Why we call that phrase "The entropy of a perfect crystal at absolute zero is exactly zero"? Isn't just the case where we have 1 possible microstate according to quantum mechanics? Therefore why to call it a law of thermodynamics?